# Better way to reverse binary

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to reverse binary like this:

```
reverse(Bin) ->
    list_to_binary(lists:reverse([rev_bits(<<B>>) || B <- binary:bin_to_list(Bin)])).


rev_bits(<<A:1, B:1, C:1, D:1, E:1, F:1, G:1, H:1>>) ->
    <<H:1, G:1, F:1, E:1, D:1, C:1, B:1, A:1>>.
```

I don't like this code.  Could you please advise better way to accomplish this routine?

Comment: What don't you like about it, what would "better" mean to you, and why do you want to reverse the bits of a number?

Comment: This version does not work if the binary has not a length multiple of byte.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot I just dislike smell of my code, it is just an exercise.

Comment: @Pascal  I see, binary is enough, no need to be compatible with bitstrings here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhat like your rev_bits function:

```
rev (<<>>, Acc) -> Acc;
rev (<<H:1/binary, Rest/binary>>, Acc) ->
    rev(Rest, <<H/binary, Acc/binary>>).
```

I believe binary concatenation is optimised so this should be quite fast already.

Edited: use clauses instead of case…of…end.

Comment: Thank you!  Recursive solution seems better here, but I rather split it into two clauses.

Comment: This will start working with bitstrings if replace every "binary" with "bits".

Answer (score 8):

**Better alternative:**

```
rev(Binary) ->

   Size = erlang:size(Binary)*8,
   <<X:Size/integer-little>> = Binary,
   <<X:Size/integer-big>>.
```

Benchmark results of comparing to fenollp iteration method. The benchmark test was done calling both functions with a random binary containing 8192 random bytes:

**Calling reverse 10 times**

BENCHMARK my method: Calling reverse/1 function 10 times. Process took 0.000299 seconds
BENCHMARK fenollp iteration method: Calling reverse_recursive/1 function 10 times. Process took 0.058528 seconds

**Calling reverse 100 times**

BENCHMARK my method: Calling reverse/1 function 100 times. Process took 0.002703 seconds
BENCHMARK fenollp iteration method: Calling reverse_recursive/1 function 100 times. Process took 0.391098 seconds

The method proposed by me is usually at least 100 times faster.

Comment: Instead of `erlang:size(Binary)*8`, you can just use `erlang:bit_size(Binary)`?

Comment: @brucify You are quite right to ask this question. I somehow got the idea that we are dealing with reversing bitstrings binaries that contains bytes only. Let's remember that for bitstrings, the number of whole bytes is returned by the erlang:size. But if if the number of bits in the binary is not divisible by 8, the resulting number of bytes is rounded down. So for an arbitrary bitstring containing 13 bit for example my erlang:size*8 will return 8 when in fact there are a total of 13 bits to be reversed and matched. I will modify my answer to include this observation. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

```
binary:encode_unsigned(binary:decode_unsigned(Bin, little)).
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.